# When Raw Material type is stockable, it's not available in manufacture order

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

It takes me hours but I still cannot find out why.

I have make MO for product A

A(manufacture in WH-A)

|----1 pcs of Part 1(stockable, 100pcs on hand in WH-A)

|----1 pcs of Part 2(stockable, 100pcs on hand in WH-A)

But when I click check availability, it always show quantity available is none.

I noticed that the supply method for raw material is Advanced: Apply Procurement Rules . and the explanation tells me that it by default check stock but I can also apply procuments, but that's not what I want, I just want it to do by default.

Why? I indeed have enough products in WH-A.

Thank you very much!

It's ODOO 10.

Comment: I already set reordering rules, but it seems that it just ignore the products on hand.